# Using raycasting to check the object in front of a Perspective Camera with first person controls

Tags: three.js

I've got a Perspective Camera and would like to use Raycasting to find the object in front of the player. I can't find any tutorials on how to do this, instead of clicking an object with the mouse pointer which I don't want to do. Where can I find out how to do this, or how do I implement this myself? Or do I just use the raycaster by itself?

Comment: Instantiate a `Raycaster` that you can reuse. Set the raycaster's origin and unit-length direction vector. Call `Raycaster.intersectObjects()`. Post your code if you have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple.
Based on the code of the raycasting example with terrain 
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast
And on this reference
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster
You can see that all you have to do is change the second parameter of the Raycaster constructor to a vector that points in the same direction as the camera does.
So the following code from the example

```
                var mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                var mouseY = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouseX, mouseY, camera.near );

                // Convert the [-1, 1] screen coordinate into a world coordinate on the near plane
                var projector = new THREE.Projector();
                projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
```

becomes

```
                var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
                vector = camera.localToWorld(vector);
                vector.sub(camera.position); // Now vector is a unit vector with the same direction as the camera

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector);
```

Using this should always create a raycaster that selects objects pointed to by the camera, independent of the type of camera you use, or its controls.